# Continuous formula drawing?

Tags: linear-algebra

WolframAlpha is good and all.

But do you know a website that could "Brute Force" formula? A site that could turn `20 + 5a` into:

```
a=1   25
a=2   30
a=3   35
a=4   40
```

Of course I could calculate myself, but sometimes I come on formulas that I need few minutes to expand with this method, while computer possibly can do it within seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha can actually do that. For example, say you wanted a table of $a^2+a-2$ for $a=1,2,3,\cdots, 11$ but didn't want to do it by hand. Go to Wolfram Alpha and enter

```
Table[a^2+a-2,{a,1,11}]
```

The format will always be

```
Table[ formula you want to calculate in terms of a,
 {a,smallest a, largest a}]
```

Moreover, if you only wanted the even $a$'s for example, then you would have entered

```
Table[a^2+a-2,{a,1,11,2}]
```

The last number, in this case $2$, tells what to increase $a$ by each time. So there it says to start at $a=1$ then add $2$ each time until $a$ is no bigger than $11$.

Comment: The result, is correct of what I am expecting. But I still don't get formula. Could you translate `20 + 5a` to this formula, so I maybe can understand it? Found it `Table[20 + 5a,{a, 0, 5}]`.

Comment: You'd type Table[20+5a,{a,1,4}] to produce the table you gave in your question. Just be warned, if you ask it to do many different $a$'s, it will stop producing a table and instead will just print the list of values you'd obtain.